# Python: How to One Hot Encode a Feature with multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df` with names of the travelling cities in `route` column of an aircraft with it's `ticket_price`.

I want to obtain individual city names from `route` and one hot encode them.

**Dataframe (`df`)**

```
id|         route               | ticket_price
1 | Mumbai - Pune - Bangalore   |   10000
2 | Pune - Delhi                |    7000
3 | Delhi - Pune                |    6500
```

**Required Dataframe (`df_encoded`)**

```
id | route_mumbai | route_pune | route_bangalore | route_delhi | ticket_price
1  |      1       |      1     |      1          |     0       |   10000
2  |      0       |      1     |      0          |     1       |    7000
3  |      0       |      1     |      0          |     1       |    6500
```

**Code**
I have performed some preprocessing on the `route` column using the following code but am unable to understand how to one hot encode it.

```
def location_preprocessing(text):

  """
  Function to Preprocess the features having location names.
  """

  text = text.replace(" ", "")    # Remove whitespaces
  text = text.split("|")          # Obtain individual cities

  lst_text = [x.lower() for x in text]    # Lowercase city names

  text = " ".join(lst_text)               # Convert to string from list

  return text

df['route'] = df['route'].apply(lambda x: location_preprocessing(x))
```

If I apply one hot encoding directly using the below code then all routes are considered unique and are one hot encoded individually which is not desired. I want individual cities to be one hot encoded not the route.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['route'])    # One-hot Encoding `route`
```

How to obtain the required dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dataframe:

```
   id                      route  ticket_price
0   1  Mumbai - Pune - Bangalore         10000
1   2               Pune - Delhi          7000
2   3               Delhi - Pune          6500
```

Then:

```
df.route = df.route.str.split(" - ")
df_out = pd.concat(
    [
        df.explode("route")
        .pivot_table(index="id", columns="route", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix("Route_"),
        df.set_index("id").ticket_price,
    ],
    axis=1,
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
    Route_Bangalore  Route_Delhi  Route_Mumbai  Route_Pune  ticket_price
id                                                                      
1                 1            0             1           1         10000
2                 0            1             0           1          7000
3                 0            1             0           1          6500
```

Comment: This works correctly, but the original dataframe is much larger and contains multiple columns other than `route` so it will be better if you could tell me how to perform this inplace and preferably without resetting the index (because the train and validation data are combined and resetting index will make it difficult to separate them).